# Attempting to connect to an oracle database from shell script

Tags: oracle, shell, unix

I am trying to connect to an oracle database from a shell script ( I am a new user ) . The script will then pass a query and transfer the result to a variable called canadacount. I have written the code but it does not work

```
#this script will attempt to connect to a remote database CFQ143 with user ID 'userid' and password 'password'.
#After loggin in it will read data from the PLATFORMSPECIFIC table.
#We can pass a query 'select count (platform) from platformspecific where platform='CANADA';
#The result from this query will be passed to a variable called canadacount which we can then echo back to the user.

canadacount='$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s /nolog<<EOF
connect userid/passsword@CFQ143:1521:CFQ143
set pages 0 feed off
select count (platform) from platformspecific where platform='CANADA';
exit
EOF'
echo $canadacount
```

Comment: The expresion "it does not work" is perfect here. That just spit the text on the screen, won't run.

Comment: what are you trying to say

Comment: Very funny Florin...might be humorous to you but not for me

Answer (score 0):

The answer is :

I changed the connect line to the following:

```
connect userid/passsword@CFQ143
```